# Non-Autoincrementing the default Rails :id field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How can I create a table where the my `:id` field will not auto-increment?

Example table:

```
cost_categories

id    description
--    -----------
94    Labor
101   Framing
750   Paint
```

**Please Note**: As far as my `:id` column goes, everything about it will be the Rails default accept the fact that I don't want it to auto-increment.

I've seen a lot of answers where they suggest not doing this, but it doesn't make sense to have, say, a rails default `:id` field AND my own `:cc_id` field.

I'd really appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For mysql DB:
In your migration file:

```
create_table :table_name, :id => false do |t|
  t.integer :id, :options => 'PRIMARY KEY'
end
```

YOu should add your index:

```
add_index(:table_name, :id, :unique => true, :name => 'id_index')
```